# Can I add more formats of date in advanced-custom-field plugin?

Tags: wordpress, date, web, plugins

I want to have Persian date format in my advanced custom field.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show a Gregorian date in a different format you can use the custom input as shown in the image.

[image: acf-date-picker-field-settings]

If I understood you well, you need the Solar Hijri Calendar known as Persian Calendar.

ACF only supports Gregorian Calendar so you can't do that in ACF, but you can find PHP classes that output the Lunar Hijri/Solar Hijri dates or some that convert from Gregorian to Hijri dates.

These links might be of help:

[HijriCalendar.class.php](https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/43092.html)

[Persian-Calendar](https://github.com/omid/Persian-Calendar/blob/master/persian_calendar.php)

[Hijri-Gregorian Calendar](https://redacacia.me/2010/08/16/coding-in-php-a-hijri-gregorian-calendar/)

[I18N_Arabic_Date](https://www.ar-php.org/I18N/Arabic/Docs/I18N_Arabic/I18N_Arabic_Date.html)